# Delete all Bookmarks / Favorites from Safari

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, bookmarks

I use Chrome as my primary browser (Work and Home) but have to fall-back to Safari for side-businesses during work, such as music streaming sites.

For consistency, I like to keep my browsers in sync. Chrome carries all my bookmarks and I prefer importing them all into Safari. An obvious limitation of this is that to keep my Safari updated with latest bookmarks of Chrome, every once in a while I must delete all bookmarks / favorites from Safari and add them again (just to avoid any duplication).

Now I'm unable to find any button in menus / preferences to Delete All Bookmarks. And deleting each bookmark individually is a pain since there are over 280. **How do I delete all bookmarks from Safari** without having to reset it entirely (deleting Cache, Cookies, History etc)?

macOS High Sierra 10.13.3, Safari 11.0.3 (13604.5.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who've been in `Apple`'s *ecosystem* for a while, this would be straight-forward. But since I come from `Windows` / `Linux` background, I'm not-so-familiar with the quick and (subjectively) *intuitive* shortcuts found here-and-there across `macOS`.

---

It's quite easy:

- Click on `Bookmarks` menu > `Edit Bookmarks`
- Here you get list of all your bookmarks and favorites (*Tip*: If you've imported your bookmarks from `Chrome`, all those that come from `Bookmarks Bar` of `Chrome` are listed under `Favorites`)
- Click on the first bookmark (after favorites section), and hold down `Delete` key till all bookmarks get deleted
  [image]
- Repeat this for `Favorites`

Comment: I would appreciate if there's some tool / `script` that can automate this *syncing* (apply changes in `Chrome`'s bookmarks to `Safari`)

Comment: Why can't I just select all bookmarks and hit the delete key?

Comment: Its great if you can. For some reason I was not able to *select all* at the time

Comment: No, I mean I really *can't*. With High Sierra. I don't understand why such a simple thing isn't implemented yet...

Comment: **@JorgeArévalo** Because you know, `Apple`..! [Watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zO0b-l-u7Yk)

Comment: it actually deletes them quite fast, like under a second for the 10 favorites for instance

Comment: I can't believe I had to do this one by one, this is horrible! I'm glad Chrome is my main browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the file by using the terminal:

```
$ rm ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

Or by the finder by going to the following path (Cmd-Shift-G):

```
~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: in my case I also needed to turn off sync with icloud (in "system preferences") and I deleted everything in `~/Library/Safari/` but that's probably not needed.

Answer (score 1):

How to delete ALL bookmarks at once:

Go to Bookmarks->Edit Bookmarks.  If you try selecting all, they all become selected, but if you right-click, they deselect.

Here's the solution:

1. create a folder called 'toss'.
2. select all the bookmarks and folders ACCEPT 'toss'.
3. drag all items into 'toss'.
4. right click on 'toss' and choose 'delete'.
5. say, "hey, thanks JR. That was too easy".

Answer (score 0):

This works in Monterey: Go to `Bookmarks` -> `Edit Bookmarks`, select the last bookmark (all the way down) and hold the delete key until they are all gone